# Can I call someone from my PC using Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i

Tags: mobile-broadband

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i, an eight year old phone running Android 2.2 'Froyo'. I connected it to my PC using USB cable. I could find that it̀s modem was connected. Can I call or text to someone from my Ubuntu(18.04 LTS) PC?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pushbullet extension](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android&referrer=utm_source%3Dpushbullet.com) to the [Chromium browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home) allows me to connect to my phon and send a text message. Chromium browser is in the [packages of Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/web/), but since your phone does not have Android 5.0 or newer, I doubt it would work since it requires Android Lollipop or better.